# How to get list of all sobject records modified today in the system?

Tags: apex, soql, query, salesforce-id, sosl

I need a list of all sobject records that got modified today. this is not just for one object but for all objects in the system. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

Simpler way? well yes and no. We have [Database.getUpdated](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_getUpdated) method that returns Id of records updated in a particular time span.

It takes sObject Type , start date and end date as arguments and returns ID of updated record.

The tricky bit is not every object is supported, so you have add ignore list or some custom logic for objects not supported by getUpdatedMethod.

```
Map<String , List<Id>> updatedObject= new Map<String,List<Id>>();
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd =
        Schema.getGlobalDescribe();

List<String> ignoreList = new List<String>();
ignoreList.add('feedattachment');
ignoreList.add('pushtopic');
ignoreList.add('apextestqueueitem');
ignoreList.add('objectpermissions');
ignoreList.add('fieldpermissions');
ignoreList.add('conversationentry');
ignoreList.add('permissionset');
ignoreList.add('oauthcustomscope');

for (String objectName : gd.keySet()) {

    if(!ignoreList.contains(objectName) && gd.get(objectName).getDescribe().Createable && gd.get(objectName).getDescribe().Updateable && !objectName.endsWith('share') && !objectName.startsWith('content') && !objectName.startsWith('collaboration')){
        Database.GetUpdatedResult updatedRecords = Database.getUpdated(objectName, System.now().addDays(-1), System.now());
        if (updatedRecords.getIds().size() > 0) {
            updatedObject.put(objectName, updatedRecords.getIds());
        }
    }


}

System.debug(updatedObject.keySet());
```