# Get all records created by user today

Tags: apex, soql, sobject

We are about to perform Load Testing and we are performing some complex scenarios. We use a CPQ tool that has many custom object records being involved and inserted. Is there an easy way to get somehow all the IDs along with their sObjectType created by the user running the test today? We need to get those IDs and delete them from the database in order to repeat scenarios.

Comment: Take a look at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/274377/87

Comment: Really helpful. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Used the code based on a similar question: [How to get list of all sobject records modified today in the system?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274367/how-to-get-list-of-all-sobject-records-modified-today-in-the-system/274377#274377)
but with some minor changes on the ignoreList list.

```
ignoreList.add('feedattachment');
ignoreList.add('pushtopic');
ignoreList.add('apextestqueueitem');
ignoreList.add('objectpermissions');
ignoreList.add('fieldpermissions');
ignoreList.add('conversationentry');
ignoreList.add('permissionset');
ignoreList.add('oauthcustomscope');
ignoreList.add('entitlementtemplate');
ignoreList.add('milestonetype');
ignoreList.add('permissionsetassignment');
ignoreList.add('permissionsettabsetting');
ignoreList.add('forecastinguserpreference');
ignoreList.add('permissionsetgroup');
ignoreList.add('emailrelay');
ignoreList.add('mutingpermissionset');
ignoreList.add('oauthcustomscopeapp');
```